# Weird CSS Padding?

Tags: html, css

So I have the following website: http://www.itmustbecollege.com/

and it has a problem SOMEWHERE that I can't seem to figure out. The problem is that all of my pages now have a big "space" on the far right, forcing a huge horizontal size.

I have tried to debug but can't seem to find out the exact problem. It is weird, because certain parts of the website have a "width: 100%" yet ENDS at the correct look, yet there is still that huge space!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width for `ul#nav` is set at 6820px.

Comment: Yes that’s the problem. A way to identify such problems is to use Firebug and use there the command for drawing borders around all block elements. It was easy in this case to see the culprit then, since only one box is grossly wide.

Comment: I tried using the Chrome inspector thingy and it wasn't showing anything when I went over that area. Thank you so much!